# How can I calculate a regression while controlling for covariance in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have been tasked with the following:

> Determine the regression to find the impact of group and sex on the outcome score while controlling for covariance-age and convariance-weight.

I know how to calculate a regression in Matlab, but I have no idea how to to do it while controlling for the covariances. How do I work them into the regression?

My data looks like this:

Group, Sex, Convariance-Age, Covariance Weight, Outcome

1 ,    1   ,  9.78645675   ,  80.35654  ,       47.875645